# Stroke is not drawn correctly (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to make a stroke for chests in a minecraft game and I almost succeeded, but for some reason it is not drawn correctly.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmqmV.png)

The screenshot shows how part of the line has disappeared. This happens when the line is on the chest. Maybe it's a texture mapping or something else. In this case, the stroke is drawn through the blocks normally.

[ScreenShot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paYp1.png)

Also, when the chest is in the dark, the outline becomes dark, although I turned off GL_LIGHTING

[ScreenShot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leJjj.png)

Here is a piece of code with which I draw the stroke

```
glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glLineWidth(2);
glColor3ub(255, 255, 255);

glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(1, -1, 0);

glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);

glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(0, -1, 0);

glVertex3f(0, -1, 0);
glVertex3f(1, -1, 0);

glVertex3f(1, -1, 0);
glVertex3f(1, -1, -1);

glVertex3f(1, -1, -1);
glVertex3f(1, 0, -1);

glVertex3f(1, -1, -1);
glVertex3f(0, -1, -1);

glVertex3f(0, -1, -1);
glVertex3f(0, -1, 0);

glVertex3f(0, -1, -1);
glVertex3f(0, 0, -1);

glVertex3f(0, 0, -1);
glVertex3f(1, 0, -1);

glVertex3f(0, 0, -1);
glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);

glVertex3f(1, 0, -1);
glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);

glEnd();

glPopAttrib();
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshots it seems that the order of rendering is the following:

1. terrain
2. outline
3. chest

Now since you have disabled `GL_DEPTH_TEST` in step 2, the fragments (pixels) that turned white (those on which the outline is drawn), won't get their depth information updated. That's because disabling `GL_DEPTH_TEST` not only disables depth *testing*, but also disables *updating* the depth information of fragments.

So when you finally draw the chest (with depth testing re-enabled), it will be drawn over all the fragments whose depth value indicates that they are behind it. That means, also over the fragments where the outline is drawn.

The black color of the outline on the third screenshot may be caused by your call to `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);`. But that's just a hunch.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231123/discussion-on-answer-by-tomek-stroke-is-not-drawn-correctly-opengl).